# Finding the values $k\in \mathbb{R}$ such that $p(y)$ is a valid pmf

Tags: sequences-and-series, probability-distributions

Let $k$ be an arbitrary real number. I want to find the values of $k$ such that

$$p(y)=k(1-k)^y$$

is a valid pmf for $y=0,1,2,\dotsc$.

I first note two conditions that this function must satisfy

1. For all $y \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, $0 \leq p(y) \leq 1$
2. $\Sigma_y \, \,p(y) = 1$

First, if $k < 0$, then $1-k > 0$. Therefore, $(1-k)^y>0$, which implies that for all $y$, $k(1-k)^y < 0$, so the first condition is dissatisfied.

Next, if $k=0,1$, then $\Sigma_y \, \, p(y) = 0$, violating the second property of a pmf.

The more interesting cases are when $0 < k < 1$ and $k > 1$.

First suppose that $0<k<1$. With some algebraic manipulations we have

$$0 < k(1-k)^y = p(y) < k < 1$$

So the first condition is satisfied.

For the second property, we have a convergent geometric series, because the ratio $1-k$ of $(1-k)^y$ is less than $1$:

\begin{align*}
\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} p(y) &= \sum_{y=0}^{\infty} k(1-k)^y \\
&= k\sum_{y=0}^{\infty} \, \, (1-k)^y \\
&= k\bigg(\frac{1}{1-(1-k)}\bigg) \\
&= 1
\end{align*}

So if $0 < k < 1$, $p(y)$ is a valid pmf.

Now suppose $1 < k$. Then $k(1-k)^y$ will either be negative or positive depending on the parity of $y$, so the first condition is not satisfied.

Therefore, for all $y\in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0}$, $p(y)=k(1-k)^y$ is a valid pmf whenever $k \in (0,1)$.

Answer (score 0):

As you have shown, this is a valid pmf if and only if $0<k<1$, in which case it is a [fairly well-known distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Geometric_distribution).